# Resizing a stargazer table in Knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

I've put together a document using knitr and while most of the document looks fine, there's one regression table that's too wide to fit on a page without some alteration.

The regression table is generated using stargazer, and is quite wide.

I've attempted to resize the entire chunk as follows:

```
{r, echo=FALSE, resize.width=10, results='asis'}

stargazer( table...)
```

but have had no luck in generating resized output.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong, is it not possible to resize these stargazer tables via chunk options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .css file to resize the output.

in the YAML add :

```
---
output: 
html_document:
    css: custom.css
---
```

and in a custom.css file you can put :

```
table {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

*it's often easier to place the custom.css in the same folder, and note that your final output will still be self-contained.*

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the options of stargazer to resize your stargazer table. Try the following for PDF output of R markdown:

```
stargazer(model_1, model_2, model_3, model_4, model_5,
          type = 'latex',
 
          header=FALSE, # to get rid of r package output text

          single.row = TRUE, # to put coefficients and standard errors on same line

          no.space = TRUE, # to remove the spaces after each line of coefficients

          column.sep.width = "3pt", # to reduce column width

          font.size = "small" # to make font size smaller

)
```