# Resize stargarzer table when type=HTML for ioslides in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, stargazer

I am new to using R Markdown to create slides presentations within RStudio. I haven't been able to find anything online that addresses my specific question. This was [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385696/how-to-adjust-the-output-width-of-rstudio-markdown-output-to-html), but I'm having the opposite problem, i.e. I am tyring to shrink HTML stargazer output to fit on a single slide. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417073/resizing-a-stargazer-table-in-knitr) is basically the same but no answers yet. Any ideas? Here is a stylized example of my markdown code:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Scott Murff"
date: "September 4, 2015"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(stargazer)
data<-data.frame(y=rnorm(30),x1=rnorm(30), x2=rnorm(30), x3=rnorm(30), x4=rnorm(30))
fit1<-lm(y~x1,data)
fit2<-lm(y~x2,data)
fit3<-lm(y~x3,data)
fit4<-lm(y~x4,data)


stargazer(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, type='html')
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your context, I haven't find a direct way through the `stargazer` options yet, however **here's a work around through the slide parameters** :

1. you can enable the `smaller` option by adding `{.smaller}` directly to the title :

   `## your slide title {.smaller}`

Source : http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#visual-appearance

you can also center it by adding `.flexbox` and `.vcenter` :

```
## your slide title {.smaller .flexbox .vcenter}
```

Source : http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#advanced-layout

However you don't have a full control of the size.

### 2. I prefer the css option :

in the YAML add :

```
---
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
---
```

then in the styles.css file (that you should place in your presentation folder), you can put :

```
.reduced{
   font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

and send it back in the attribute of your title slide, and you're good :

```
## your slide title {.reduced}
```

source : http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#visual-appearance in the custom css paragraph

Your final html output is still self-contained and with the css file you can manage even more customization.

*After that you'll be able to use with more effectively the stargazer arguments like `single.row=TRUE` or `omit.table.layout` if you want to pursue the [customization of your stargazer table](http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html).*

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer. Both methods work and accomplish exactly what I need. I love the customization the CSS approach provides. Thanks!